# why isn't the compiler able to optimize this Code?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

What makes the compiler able to optimize this code :

```
inline U64 sKnights(U64 knights) {
        U64 l1 = (knights >> 1) & NFileH;
        U64 l2 = (knights >> 2) & NFileGH;
        U64 r1 = (knights << 1) & NFileA;
        U64 r2 = (knights << 2) & NFileAB;
        U64 h1 = l1 | r1;
        U64 h2 = l2 | r2;
        return (h1 << 16) | (h1 >> 16) | (h2 << 8) | (h2 >> 8);
    }
```

but not this:

```
inline U64 sLKnights(U64 knights)
    {
        return (((knights >> 1 & NFileH) | (knights << 1 & NFileA)) << 16) | (((knights >> 1 & NFileH) | (knights << 1 & NFileA)) >> 16) | (((knights >> 2 & NFileGH) | (knights << 2 & NFileAB)) << 8) | (((knights >> 2 & NFileGH) | (knights << 2 & NFileAB)) >> 8);
    }
```

using this code to measure performance :

```
 LARGE_INTEGER st, en, freq, dur;
unsigned long long sum=0;
dur.QuadPart = 0;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
for (size_t k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&st);
    for (unsigned long long i = 1ull; i < 10000; i++)
        X; 
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&en);
    dur.QuadPart += en.QuadPart - st.QuadPart;
}
cout << sum << endl << (dur.QuadPart / 10000) * 1000000 / freq.QuadPart << endl;
```

the Results are like This:
Method#1: 32
Method#2: 43

the assembly of the second method is longer than that of method#1,the program used is Microsoft Visual studio 2014 CTP3

Comment: Why do you think the compiler can handle everything? Optimization is based on some rules and code patterns, and if nothing is applicable, the compiler can´t optimize it. It´s no intelligent being.

Comment: 1. What do you expect would be the generated code (in both method), what was the actual generated code. 2. Profiling with time have some range of error (dependent of external activities).

Comment: @deviantfan the second method is exactly the same as the first one with the only difference being replacing the return expression variables with their equations

Comment: @NetVipeC assembly isn't my thing so I can't expect the form of the generate code, and I know profiling with time have some rang of errors but when it comes to this example the difference (11) is far from being a measurement error ,by the way the measurement is exactly the same every time I test it.

Comment: @jhon: "the second method is exactly the same": Doesn´t matter. And no, in terms if register usage etc. on pre-optimized asm level (and/or the internal representation in the compiler), nothing is the same.